# dropdown stays visual

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i have a tempcomb built into excel (i have only basic knowledge)
below the code:

```
Private Sub TempCombo_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim xCombox As ComboBox
     Dim xStr As String
     Dim xWs As Worksheet
     Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    ' On Error Resume Next
     Set xCombox = Me.TempCombo ' xWs.OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
     If HasValidation(Target) Then
         If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
             Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
             Cancel = True
             xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
             xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
             If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
             With xCombox
                 .Visible = True
                 .Left = Target.Left - 1
                 .Top = Target.Top - 1
                 .Width = Target.Width + 5
                 .Height = Target.Height + 3
                 If xStr = "Opleiding" Then
                     xStr = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Names("Opleiding").RefersTo, 2)
                 End If
                 .ListFillRange = xStr
                 .LinkedCell = Target.Address
             End With
             'Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
         End If
     End If
 End Sub



Function HasValidation(rngD As Range)
     Dim intType As Integer
     On Error Resume Next
     intType = rngD.Validation.Type
     HasValidation = (Err = 0)
 End Function
```

the perhaps simple problem i have is that the drop down stay visual also when i click somewhere else in the file, of course when a click a diff drop-down is goes with.
how can i change the code so it does not stays visual in the file?

[image]

Comment: Is this a form control or active X?

Comment: hello braX active x

Comment: Within `With xCombox`, add the following line: `.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent`

Comment: then i get a error.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: changed into:             With xCombox
                 .Visible = True
                 .Left = Target.Left - 1
                 .Top = Target.Top - 1
                 .Width = Target.Width + 5
                 .Height = Target.Height + 3
                 .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                 End If
                 .ListFillRange = xStr
                 .LinkedCell = Target.Address
             End With
             'Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
         End If
     End If
 End Sub

Comment: its work but i get double text in the box

Comment: With xCombox
                 .Visible = True
                 .Left = Target.Left - 1
                 .Top = Target.Top - 1
                 .Width = Target.Width + 5
                 .Height = Target.Height + 3
                 .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                 If xStr = "Opleiding" Then
                     xStr = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Names("Opleiding").RefersTo, 2)
                 End If
                 .ListFillRange = xStr
                 .LinkedCell = Target.Address

Comment: Is there any reason you're using ActiveX?

Comment: I just want the box temp visual i have +/- 30.000 in the file